# Chamar uma função do AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou a tentar buscar o ID do utilizador logado desta forma:

```
public int CurrentUserID()
{            
    return Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());
}
```

Este método está em `AccountController` e eu quero chamá-la de outro controlador qualquer. A função não é reconhecida e queria saber porque e como corrigir.

Comment: Como assim não reconhecida? Qual o erro informado pelo compilador? Provavelmente você está esquecendo de alguma referência ou `using`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o método precisa ser usado em vários *controllers* ele não deveria estar no `AccountController`, pelo menos não logicamente. Acho que é possível fazer isso instanciando o *controller* em questão e chamando o método, mas isso não me parece ser algo muito comum, nunca vi ninguém fazendo isso, mas também não sei dizer se é problemático ou não.

Existem várias formas de fazer isso funcionar do jeito que pretende, vou te dar um exemplo de uma maneira simples, fácil e rápida.

Crie um *controller* genérico chamado **`Controller`**, assim todos os *controllers* criados no seu projeto herdarão dele e você poderá usar este método (e outros que forem criados) em qualquer *controller*.

Note que é necessário usar o *namespace* completo do lado direito dos dois pontos.

```
public class Controller : System.Web.Mvc.Controller
{
    public int CurrentUserId()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua pergunta está com poucos detalhes, mas quase garantido que você está esquecendo de adicionar alguma referência (using) ou os controllers podem estar em namespaces distintos.

Caso esteja com dificuldades para chamar actions de outros controllers, o método [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) pode te auxiliar nestas chamadas em diferentes controllers.

Caso esteja tentando chamar seu User.Identity.GetUserId() de outro controller, é necessário adicionar a referência deste local (User). (Tente o famoso "CTRL + ." para ver se o VS não resolve isso para vc).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá Bruno, tudo certo? Então, a pergunta se refere em acessar um método de outro controller. Um **RedirectToAction()** não se encaixa neste modelo. O **Copy&Paste** até funcionaria, mas é algo inviável se ele for utilizar em mais lugares. A forma que eu faria é a que está na resposta do @jbueno. Quando tiver um tempo, dê uma olhada e veja se concorda. :p